# HTML/CSS: Из header-а выпадает блок, странное поведение при изменении окна браузера

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте! Помогите пожалуйста - учу CSS, делал учебное задание и столкнулся со странным поведением блоков при ресайзе окна браузера, видео - https://youtu.be/mH46pfLHJLE (обьяснить словами тут тяжело...).

1. Почему серый блок "не тянется" на всю ширину, а с боку белый фон?
2. Как с этим бороться?

Код HTML, CSS:

```css
body{
    font-family: "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
    color: #283136;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
}

.wrapper{
    width: 880px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.clearfix:after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

/* Header */
header{
    margin-bottom: 53px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.index-logo{
    margin-top: 28px;
    width: 139;
    height: 56px;
    float: left;
}

.index-logo img{
    width: 139;
    height: 56px;
}

.main-navigation{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 183px;
}

.main-navigation ul{
    padding: 55px 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 0;
}

.main-navigation li{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 45px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.main-navigation li:last-child{
    margin-right: 0;
}

.main-navigation a{
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-navigation .selected{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fb565a;
}

.main-navigation a:hover{
    color: #fb565a;
}

.main-navigation a:active{
    color: #000;
    opacity: 0.4;
}

.shopping-cart{
    padding: 55px 0;
    float: right;
}

.shopping-cart a{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.shopping-cart a::before{
    content: "";
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 2px;
    background: #eee url("../images/sprite.png") no-repeat 0px 0px;
}

.shopping-cart a:hover::before{
    background: #eee url("../images/sprite.png") no-repeat 0px -35px;
}

.shopping-cart a:active::before{
    background: #eee url("../images/sprite.png") no-repeat 0px 0px;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="wrapper clearfix">
            <div class="index-logo">
                <img src="images/nerds-logo.png" alt="Nerds Project" width="139" height="56">
            </div>
            <nav class="main-navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a class="selected" href="#">Студия</a> 
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Клиенты</a> 
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Магазин</a> 
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Контакты</a> 
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="shopping-cart">
                <a href="#">Корзина</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Спасибо!

Comment: у вас wrapper 800рх , и обнулите отступы : `*{margin:0; padding:0;}` дальше хотите что бы блок был резиновый - то делайте размер в %

Comment: Если хєдеру поставить ширину 100%, это ничего не даст в данном случае.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно так попробовать:

```
/* Header */
    header{
        margin: 0;
        margin-bottom: 53px;
        background-color: #eee;
        min-width: 880px;
        width: 100%;    
    }
```

Весь код:

```css
body{
    font-family: "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
    color: #283136;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
}

.wrapper{
    width: 880px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.clearfix:after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

/* Header */
header{
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 53px;
    background-color: #eee;
    min-width: 880px;
    width: 100%;    
}

.index-logo{
    margin-top: 28px;
    width: 139px;
    height: 56px;
    float: left;
}

.index-logo img{
    width: 139px;
    height: 56px;
}

.main-navigation{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 183px;
}

.main-navigation ul{
    padding: 55px 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 0;
}

.main-navigation li{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 45px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.main-navigation li:last-child{
    margin-right: 0;
}

.main-navigation a{
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-navigation .selected{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fb565a;
}

.main-navigation a:hover{
    color: #fb565a;
}

.main-navigation a:active{
    color: #000;
    opacity: 0.4;
}

.shopping-cart{
    padding: 55px 0;
    float: right;
}

.shopping-cart a{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.shopping-cart a::before{
    content: "";
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 2px;
    background: #eee url("../images/sprite.png") no-repeat 0px 0px;
}

.shopping-cart a:hover::before{
    background: #eee url("../images/sprite.png") no-repeat 0px -35px;
}

.shopping-cart a:active::before{
    background: #eee url("../images/sprite.png") no-repeat 0px 0px;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="wrapper clearfix">
            <div class="index-logo">
                <img src="images/nerds-logo.png" alt="Nerds Project" width="139" height="56">
            </div>
            <nav class="main-navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a class="selected" href="#">Студия</a> 
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Клиенты</a> 
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Магазин</a> 
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Контакты</a> 
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="shopping-cart">
                <a href="#">Корзина</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: спасибо огромное. работает очень круто! Видео - https://youtu.be/aEQ4xmAw95I